# Render arbitrary RecyclerView children to Canvas?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-canvas

Attempting to write a Java method that can take in a RecyclerView (or it's adapter or its layoutmanager) and spit out a large bitmap that is a rendering of all the RecyclerView's children as they would look if the device's screen size was the whole length of the whole finite list.

`mRecyclerView.draw(canvas)` works to render all of the currently visible children, but `mRecycler.getChildAt(x)` where x > the visible positions always returns null.

Open to any approach, as really the only goal is use Android's existing view rendering system to generate this large bitmap, and not have to custom-write my own data -> bitmap code

Comment: What you're asking for goes against the point of RecyclerView-  that all items are NOT assigned views for efficiency.  If you wanted to do that, you'd be better off not using RecyclerView at all and just using a giant ScrollView (and accepting you'll go OOM sooner rather than later).

Answer (score 2):

Due to the way the RecyclerView works (reusing views and binding data to the views when required) there is not any given time when all your RecyclerView views are fully available in memory. If interrupting the user interface is not an issue you could perhaps use RecyclerView.scrollToPosition to scroll through the RecyclerView to force it to render all the views. You could collect Bitmaps of each section when visible and combine the Bitmaps if necessary.